# Select good and bad rated in alternating fashion

Tags: mysql

I need to somehow select from a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
score INT
);
INSERT INTO reviews (score) VALUES 
(3),
(4),
(10),
(7),
(9),
(9),
(5),
(2),
(2),
(3);
```

Some reviews have a good score, other reviews have a bad score
I want to select them in this order

- 1st Best score
- 2nd Worst score
- 3rd Second best score
- 4th Second worst score

if the score is a tie then the `id` should be used for ordering

In essence the objective is to show the good and the bad side by side, if the query becomes way too complicated then it would be enough to just select one of the best and one of the worst, it would be as easy as selecting all of them and then sorting it in the server side language except the select must be limited.

I have slaved over this for the past few days and my brain simply can't handle it

EDIT:
I have edited the question as requested, [here is the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c915/18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange way to get data.  You can do this more easily in other databases using `row_number()`.  You can also do a solution in MySQL using variables.  Start by enumerating by the rows:

```
select r.*,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
from reviews r cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
order by r.score;
```

After this runs, the variable `@rn` will have the number of rows.  I think you can do what you want by doing something like:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from reviews r cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by r.score
     ) r
order by abs(2*rn - @rn), rn;
```

Comment: I don't think the expression in the ORDER BY meets the specification. I'd use something like: `ORDER BY IF(r.rn<=CEILING(@rn/2),2*r.rn-1,(CEILING(@rn+1)-r.rn)*2)`

Comment: Otherwise, this is exactly the approach I would use to emulate the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function (which is not available in MySQL). I think the specification also calls for adding `id` as a second expression in the ORDER BY in the inline view (`r`).

Comment: I have combined your answers and put an exception for `NULL`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c915/17